# How to search a token for a specific word in Java?

Tags: java, string, loops

I have a segment of code that splits a string into tokens and prints them each out on a new line. I am having a hard time writing a code that determines if a word is a reserved word or not. I have to print "Reserved word is: " if the word is a java keyword, otherwise print "Current word is: ". Here is my code so far:

```
package projectweek3;

/**
 * 
 * Name - 
 * Email Address - 
 * Date - 
 * 
 */
public class Week3Project {
    final static String program = "/*\n" +
" * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.\n" +
" * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates\n" +
" * and open the template in the editor.\n" +
" */\n" +
"package testapplication2;\n" +
"\n" +
"import java.util.Scanner;\n" +
"\n" +
"/**\n" +
" *\n" +
" * @author james\n" +
" */\n" +
"public class TestApplication2 {\n" +
"\n" +
"    /**\n" +
"     * @param args the command line arguments\n" +
"     */\n" +
"    public static void main(String[] args) {\n" +
"        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);\n" +
"        \n" +
"        System.out.println(\"Enter integer #1\");\n" +
"        int num1 = input.nextInt();\n" +
"        \n" +
"        System.out.println(\"Enter integer #2\");\n" +
"        int num2 = input.nextInt();\n" +
"        \n" +
"        System.out.println(\"Enter integer #3\");\n" +
"        int num3 = input.nextInt();\n" +
"        \n" +
"        System.out.println(\"Enter integer #4\");\n" +
"        int num4 = input.nextInt();\n" +
"        \n" +
"        System.out.println(\"Enter integer #5\");\n" +
"        int num5 = input.nextInt();\n" +
"        \n" +
"        //determine the sum\n" +
"        int sum = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5;\n" +
"        \n" +
"        //this is helpful to make sure your sum is correct\n" +
"        System.out.println(\"The sum is: \" + sum);\n" +
"        \n" +
"        //why doesn't this generate the sum correctly\n" +
"        double average = sum / 5;\n" +
"        \n" +
"        //The average, lets hope its right...\n" +
"        System.out.println(\"The average of your numbers is: \" + average);\n" +
"        \n" +
"    }\n" +
"    \n" +
"}\n" +
"";


    **public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = program;

        String s = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            s += str.charAt(i) + "";
            if (str.charAt(i) == ' ' || str.charAt(i) == '\t' || str.charAt(i) == '\n' || (str.charAt(i) == ' ' && str.charAt(i) == '\n')) {
                String currentWord = s.toString();
                String res = "int";
                        if (currentWord.equals(res)) {
                            System.out.println("Reserved word is: [" + currentWord + "]");
            }
                            else {
                                    System.out.println("Current word is: [" + currentWord + "]");
                        }

                s = "";//Clear the string to get it ready to build next token.


            }
        }**
```

Comment: you would need an array of Strings to compare with (i.e. `["public", "int", "for", etc...]` ). The String array would contain all reserved words in Java. Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) for a list of reserved words

Comment: Ok. So I create a string with every reserved word and do I use .equals to compare?

Comment: Yes, you create a string **array** with all reserved words and use `.equals` to compare them. This is what I would do. You may want to create a separate method to do the comparisons in

Comment: All the reserved words (or keywords) would be contained within a Single dimensional String Array: `String[] keywords = {"abstract", "assert", "boolean", ... etc }`. Once you have established a word from your input string you would run that word through a inner **for** loop and compare against each element of the keywords array: `boolean iskeyword = false; for (int j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) { if (stringWord.equalsIgnoreCase(keywords[j])) { isKeyWord = true; break; } }`. Display your results based on whether **isKeyword** is true or false after the inner **for** loop.

Comment: In the interest of time complexity, consider using set.contains() rather than iterative comparison over a list.

Answer (score 0):

I would reconsider the way you're looping through the "program."

Instead of going through character by character, use the Java String.split() function.

```
String program = "int num1 = input.nextInt();\n";

String[] words = program.split("[\\n\\s\\t]");
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Output:

```
int
num1
=
input.nextInt();
```

**EDIT:**

Since you can't use String.split(), your looping solution looks good. To check if the current word is reserved, try using Set.contains().

```
Set<String> reserved = new HashSet<>();
reserved.add("int");

// ...

if reserved.contains(word) {
    System.out.println("Reserved word is: " + word);
} else {
    System.out.println("Current word is: " + word);
}
```

That is, assuming you're allowed to use Set.

Comment: I would, but I am required to use a for loop. I can't use split, scan or tokenizer.